# SQL to get the closest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which is giving me the closest date but not properly, it works only one way

```
select *
from Table1
where id = 80
  and startdate = (select top 1 startdate 
                   from Table1 
                   where id = 80
                   order by abs(convert(float, getdate() - StartDate)))
```

Where I want to make sure that if there is date which is bigger and date which is lesser to the selected date has least difference, it should pick that record.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Could you give more context to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: there is date say as: 12-12-2019, and i have other records whose dates are 01-01-2020, 12-11-2019 and lots more, so i am trying to pick the date which is closest to my current date which is 12-12-2019, either it could be the one which is year 2020 or lesser one depending upon which has less days

Comment: Are you saying that for *each* row in the table you want to return the *closest* date from the entire rest of the table?

Comment: suppose i have 10 rows, and one row is being added, i want that the new row should get the closest date from all the previous rows

Comment: Can you please show us the results you are getting and why they aren't the results you want?  Also sample data that exists in Table1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows with a data similar to the `startdate` with `id = 80` you can use something like this:

```
select top (3) t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             max(case when id = 80 then startdate end) over () as date_80
      from Table1 t1
     ) t1
order by abs(datediff(day, startdate, date_80));
```

If you want one record:

```
select top (1) t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             max(case when id = 80 then startdate end) over () as date_80
      from Table1 t1
     ) t1
where id <> 80
order by abs(datediff(day, startdate, date_80))
```

Comment: what you mean by around 80, 80 is the id value passed for the selected rows related to that id and they can dates , lesser or bigger, i just need to get the closest one

Comment: @GMX . . . That appears to be what the OP is trying to do.  I clarified that sentence.

Comment: I think you are confusing me, i want a closest date to 5 rows i have, it could the date which is greater than selected date or letter one, based upon least number of days gap

Comment: @GMX . . . The `abs()` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

in case of a scenario like it is today 10th Dec and you have 15th Dec and 5th Dec, sub-ordering the records that are nearest by startdate descending has to put the later date at the top of the list.

I would also use the built in function DATEDIFF, treating dates as FLOAT is an old technique with some drawbacks, including possible confusions regarding fractions of days

```
    select * from Table1 where id = 80 
         and startdate = (select top 1 startdate from Table1 
         where id = 80 
            order by 
                abs(DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),startdate)) ASC,  --use a built in function over FLOAT
                StartDate DESC)    --If there are equidistant dates, this will take the higher of those dates
```

Comment: the code you gave me, its like there are two existing dates, 27-11-2019 and 30-11-2019, added a new record with dec1st as a date, it should pick 30th nov as that is closest, but it is picking 27th

Comment: issue seems to be the getdate

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to add `startdate<>t1.startdate` as below in your query. The absence of which might have cause same startdates as output

```
     select * from Table1 t1
      where id = 80 
     and startdate = (select top 1 
    startdate from Table1 
     where id = 80 and startdate<>t1. 
     startdate order by 
    abs(convert(float,getdate() - 
     StartDate)))
```